# Trying to scrape html from webpage, but not getting the right class name/hierarchy for Document.getClass

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the text of 3 `<a> some text </a>` links from a webpage and am using a Swift method that uses javascript to get the class/id/html element to scrape it. Except, I'm not getting the right class or id from the html.

I tried to use `document.getElementsByClassName/Id` and call all the classes/id to the one I need, but I'm getting an error:

> ```
> 'document.getElementByClass('col-sm-12 col-md-9')', 'document.getElementByClass' is undefined
> ```

and I don't know why. Can someone point me in the right direction to solving this or point out my error?

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {

//I'm calling all the classes and ids
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementByClass('col-sm-12 col-md-9').document.getElementById('content-top').getElementsByClassName('item hero-container item-container item-content tag-links')") {(result, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            print(error!)
            return
        }

        print(String(describing: result))
    }
}
```

Comment: [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) with 's' and 'Name'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `getElementByClass` DOM function. The closest match would be `getElementsByClassName` (note the `s` and `Name`), but that would accept a single class, and return an array.

You probably want to use `document.querySelectorAll` instead, and you can give it a full CSS selector directly (so you need to prefix classes with `.` and ids with `#` and leave no space for classes on the same element:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.tag-links a')
```

should be enough if there's a single element with class `tag-links` in the page.

Comment: Thank you. I tried both querySelectorAll and full Css selector and they both work now. thank you for showing me this